# Bind to validation error in ErrorTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, templates, binding

I'm currently writing an application which should validate its forms via IDataErrorInfo.

My ViewModel implements it and it plain works. The problem is i need to change the border around my control according to the given validation error string.
My current implementation works only for the first validation, after that the triggers are not being triggered again.

My View.xaml (partial):

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"  MaxLength="10" Text="{Binding Code, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"/>
```

My ErrorTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
    <Border BorderThickness="2" x:Name="ValidationBorder">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ValidationElement"/>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ValidationElement, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource ValidationConverter}}" Value="NotValid">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ValidationElement, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource ValidationConverter}}" Value="Valid">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LawnGreen"/>

                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>    
</ControlTemplate>
```

I set a breakpoint into the converter, i get the right value, but the problem persists, the trigger is only being fired once and after that never again.

Any suggestions what i may have missed?